# HDMI not working on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: hdmi, 17.04

I have an Asus ROG G46VW and an LG TV that I normally use as a monitor (for Windows). Whenever I try to connect the laptop to the TV I do not get a signal and I do not know what to do to fix this.

Comment: The Asus ROG G46VW has a Nvidia graphics card that may require Nvidia proprietary drivers.

Comment: To expand on MichaelBay answer, if you haven't installed the nVidia drivers yet, just look for "Additional Drivers" on the Dash and select the appropriate nVidia drivers. You might also want to try with this PPA https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Last, I've encountered a bug with the latest nVidia drivers and sound, so if you can't play sound on your TV, let me know

Comment: The HDMI works now but I wanted to extend my tv display and I do not know how to do that.